# qaction translating

Tags: windows, qt

I have some problems with translating QActions
In translation file there is translation for FILETAB_* Strings
but in application these translation isn't used And user see
 FILETAB_OPEN_FILE for example.
can any one help with this?

```
void Application::setLanguage(const QString& locale)
{
    // remove previous
    if (current)
    {
        removeTranslator(current);
    }
    current_locale=locale;
    // install new

    current = translators.value(locale, 0);
    if (current)
    {
        installTranslator(current);
    }
}
void MainWindow::changeEvent(QEvent *event)
{
 if (event->type()==QEvent::LanguageChange)
 {
    retranslateUi(this);
 }
 QMainWindow::changeEvent(event);
}
void MainWindow::setupFileTabel()
{
    fileTableWidget->setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectRows);
    fileTableWidget->setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::CustomContextMenu);
    setupFileTabelContextMenu();
}
void MainWindow::setupFileTabelContextMenu()
{
    fileTabMenu = new QMenu(fileTableWidget);
    openFile = new QAction(tr("FILETAB_OPEN_FILE"), fileTabMenu);
    QObject::connect(openFile, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(OpenFileSelected()));
    fileTabMenu->addAction(openFile);
    openDir = new QAction(tr("FILETAB_OPEN_FOLDER"), this);
    QObject::connect(openDir, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(OpenDirSelected()));
    fileTabMenu->addAction(openDir);
    fileTabMenu->addSeparator();
    priority = new QMenu(fileTabMenu);
    priority->setTitle(tr("FILETAB_PRIORITY"));
    lowPriority = new QAction(tr("FILETAB_PRIORITY_LOW"), fileTabMenu);
    lowPriority->setCheckable(true);
    QObject::connect(lowPriority, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(setLowForCurrentFile()));
    priority->addAction(lowPriority);
    mediumPriority = new QAction(tr("FILETAB_PRIORITY_MEDIUM"), fileTabMenu);
    mediumPriority->setCheckable(true);
    QObject::connect(mediumPriority, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(setMediumForCurrentFile()));
    priority->addAction(mediumPriority);
    highPriority = new QAction(tr("FILETAB_PRIORITY_HIGH"), fileTabMenu);
    highPriority->setCheckable(true);
    QObject::connect(highPriority, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(setHighForCurrentFile()));
    priority->addAction(highPriority);
    fileTabMenu->addMenu(priority);
    fileTabMenu->addSeparator();
    dontDownload = new QAction(tr("FILETAB_PRIORITY_ZERO"), fileTabMenu);
    dontDownload->setCheckable(true);
    QObject::connect(dontDownload, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(setNotDownloadForCurrentFile()));
    fileTabMenu->addAction(dontDownload);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first argument of the QAction is not the name of the action, it is the text that will appear in the menu for that action. The tr() function marks the string that is passed in as a string that should be localized. Have a look here for an explanation.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/internationalization.html#use-tr-for-all-literal-text